# 2nd thread not able to receive messages via message queue sent by thread 1 in C/C++/linux

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, ipc, message-queue

I am simulating a udp server which receives multiple request messages via udp client. I need to spawn 2 threads in this udp server sample code. thread 1 will receive all the udp request as and when they arrive and sent it to thread 2 via message queue for processing.

**thread 1(SndMq)** is able to receive the request message at via udp and also able to put it in message queue using a structure. But the problem is the **thread 2(RcvMq)** is not able to read even single message in the message queue. Please suggest any solution.

**Error part (thread 2 function):**

```
void* RcvMq(void*) {

        time_t t2;
        time(&t2);

        msgst *msg = new msgst;

        int mqid = msgget((key_t)12345, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
        if (mqid == -1) {
                printf("thread 2: msgget failed with error: %d\n", errno);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else
            printf("\nthread 2: got MQ id: %d\n", mqid);

        long receive_m_type = 123;

        printf("thread 2: going to enter while(1) loop\n");
        while(1) {
                printf("\nthread 2: inside while(1) loop, going to msgrcv()\n");
                if ( msgrcv(mqid, (void *)&msg, BUFSIZE, receive_m_type, 0) < 0 ) {
                        //printf("\nthread 2: msgrcv failed with error: [%s]\n", strerror(errno));
                        printf("\nthread 2: msgrcv failed with error\n");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                else {
                        printf("thread 2: going to ctime()\n");
                        printf("\nthread 2: DeQueued at: %s\n", ctime(&t2));
                }
                printf("\nthread 2: going to print struct's buffer\n");
                printf("thread 2: Message received at MQ rcv is: %s \n", msg->buffer);
        }
}
```

**code for udp server simulator**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include<pthread.h>

#define PORT 5000
#define BUFSIZE 2048

pthread_t sndtid;
pthread_t rcvtid;

typedef struct msgst  {
        long int mtype;
        char buffer[BUFSIZE];
    }msgst;

void* SndMq(void*) {

        time_t t1;
        time(&t1);
        struct sockaddr_in myaddr;  /* our address */
        struct sockaddr_in remaddr; /* remote address */
        socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(remaddr);    /* length of addresses */
        int recvlen;                /* # bytes received */
        int fd;                     /* our socket */
        int rc, on=1;
        char buf[BUFSIZE];  /* receive buffer */
        size_t buflen;
        /* create a UDP socket: socket, setsockopt, bind */
        if ((fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
                perror("cannot create socket\n");
                return 0;
        }
        if((rc = setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&on, sizeof(on))) < 0) {
                perror("thread 1: UDP Server setsockopt() - ERROR");
                close(fd);
                exit(-1);
        }
        /* bind the socket to any valid IP address and a specific port */
        memset((char *)&myaddr, 0, sizeof(myaddr));
        myaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        myaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
        //myaddr.sin_port = htons(SERVICE_PORT);
        myaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
        if (    bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&myaddr, sizeof(myaddr) ) < 0) {
                perror("bind failed");
                return 0;
        }

        printf("\nthread 1: Server waiting on port %d\n", PORT);

        //MsgQ implementation:
        int mqid = msgget((key_t)12345, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
        if(mqid == -1) {
                printf("thread 1: msgget() failed, errno: %d\n",errno );
        }
        else
            printf("thread 1: created MQ id: %d\n", mqid);

        /* now loop, receiving data and printing what we received */
        for (;;) {

                //rcv from udp client
                recvlen = recvfrom(fd, buf, BUFSIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&remaddr, &addrlen);
                printf("\nthread 1: received %d bytes\n", recvlen);
                if (recvlen > 0) {
                        buf[recvlen] = 0;
                        printf("thread 1: received message from UDP client: %s\n", buf);
                }

                //send received msg via MsgQ
                msgst *msgptr = new msgst;
                msgptr->mtype = 123;
                strcpy(msgptr->buffer, buf);
                //msgptr->buffer=buf;
                //memcpy(msgptr->buffer, buf, BUFSIZE);
                buflen = strlen(msgptr->buffer);

                if (msgsnd(mqid, (void *)&msgptr, buflen, IPC_NOWAIT) == -1) {
                        printf("thread 1: msgsnd failed\n");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                printf("thread 1: added Req to MsgQ at: %s\n", ctime(&t1));
        }/* never exits */
    }
void* RcvMq(void*) {

        time_t t2;
        time(&t2);

        msgst *msg = new msgst;

        int mqid = msgget((key_t)12345, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
        if (mqid == -1) {
                printf("thread 2: msgget failed with error: %d\n", errno);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else
            printf("\nthread 2: got MQ id: %d\n", mqid);

        long receive_m_type = 123;

        printf("thread 2: going to enter while(1) loop\n");
        while(1) {
                printf("\nthread 2: inside while(1) loop, going to msgrcv()\n");
                if ( msgrcv(mqid, (void *)&msg, BUFSIZE, receive_m_type, 0) < 0 ) {
                        //printf("\nthread 2: msgrcv failed with error: [%s]\n", strerror(errno));
                        printf("\nthread 2: msgrcv failed with error\n");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                else {
                        printf("thread 2: going to ctime()\n");
                        printf("\nthread 2: DeQueued at: %s\n", ctime(&t2));
                }
                printf("\nthread 2: going to print struct's buffer\n");
                printf("thread 2: Message received at MQ rcv is: %s \n", msg->buffer);
        }
}
int main() {

        int rtn=0;

        rtn = pthread_create(&(sndtid), NULL, &SndMq, NULL);
        if (rtn != 0)
                printf("\ncan't create thread SndMq, error:[%s]", strerror(rtn));
        else
                printf("\n\ncreated SndMq thread\n");

        rtn = pthread_create(&(rcvtid), NULL, &RcvMq, NULL);
        if (rtn != 0)
                printf("\ncan't create thread RcvMq :[%s]", strerror(rtn));
        else
                printf("created RcvMq thread\n");

        printf("main(): All threads spawned successfully, now waiting for threads to end...\n");
        pthread_join(sndtid, NULL);
        pthread_join(rcvtid, NULL);
        printf("\nThreads ended, main() exiting now...\n");

        return 0;
}
```

### output:

```
created SndMq thread
created RcvMq thread
main(): All threads spawned successfully, now waiting for threads to end...

thread 2: got MQ id: 6422528
thread 2: going to enter while(1) loop

thread 2: inside while(1) loop, going to msgrcv()

thread 1: Server waiting on port 5000
thread 1: created MQ id: 6422528

thread 1: received 1500 bytes
thread 1: received message from UDP client: <TransactionId>1</TransactionId>
thread 1: added Req to MsgQ at: Sat Apr  5 18:16:45 2014


thread 1: received 1500 bytes
thread 1: received message from UDP client: <TransactionId>2</TransactionId>
thread 1: added Req to MsgQ at: Sat Apr  5 18:16:45 2014


thread 1: received 1500 bytes
thread 1: received message from UDP client: <TransactionId>3</TransactionId>
thread 1: added Req to MsgQ at: Sat Apr  5 18:16:45 2014


thread 1: received 1500 bytes
thread 1: received message from UDP client: <TransactionId>4</TransactionId>
thread 1: added Req to MsgQ at: Sat Apr  5 18:16:45 2014


thread 1: received 1500 bytes
thread 1: received message from UDP client: <TransactionId>5</TransactionId>
thread 1: added Req to MsgQ at: Sat Apr  5 18:16:45 2014


thread 1: received 1500 bytes
thread 1: received message from UDP client: <TransactionId>6</TransactionId>
thread 1: added Req to MsgQ at: Sat Apr  5 18:16:45 2014


thread 1: received 1500 bytes
thread 1: received message from UDP client: <TransactionId>7</TransactionId>
thread 1: added Req to MsgQ at: Sat Apr  5 18:16:45 2014


thread 1: received 1500 bytes
thread 1: received message from UDP client: <TransactionId>8</TransactionId>
thread 1: added Req to MsgQ at: Sat Apr  5 18:16:45 2014


thread 1: received 1500 bytes
thread 1: received message from UDP client: <TransactionId>9</TransactionId>
thread 1: added Req to MsgQ at: Sat Apr  5 18:16:45 2014


thread 1: received 1500 bytes
thread 1: received message from UDP client: <TransactionId>10</TransactionId>
thread 1: added Req to MsgQ at: Sat Apr  5 18:16:45 2014
```

Comment: Boil your code down to something much simpler and shorter.  Something "minimal."

Comment: @JohnZwinck you can check only the `void* RcvMq(void*)` part which has error in receiving message queue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Your primary problem is a C error.  You are passing the address of a ptr (a ptr to ptr) rather than the pointer.

```
msgst *msgptr = new msgst;
//...

if (msgsnd(mqid, (void *)&msgptr, buflen, IPC_NOWAIT) == -1)
```

Should be

```
if (msgsnd(mqid, (void *) msgptr, buflen, IPC_NOWAIT) == -1)
```

As a result you are writing whatever random junk is at &msgptr and since you are writing msgtype 123 and then trying to read msgtype 123 later (but wrote junk) you will never (or very rarely!) find that message type.

You make the same mistake on the message receive side:

```
msgst *msg = new msgst;
//.......

if ( msgrcv(mqid, (void *)&msg, BUFSIZE, receive_m_type, 0) < 0 )
```

(2) You probably didn't get to it yet but you have a memory leak because you `new` the buffer but never `delete` it.  You don't really need dynamic memory allocation here anyway.  It would be easier to just have the buffer allocated on the stack because it just going to be copied by `msgsnd` anyway and then you are done with it.  This would have also eliminated the problem you ran into with (1).

(3) You are going to run into problems with IPC_NOWAIT on the `msgsnd`.  It will be very easy to fill the queue on the producer side before they get processed by the consumer.  At the very least you should be checking for EAGAIN and taking whatever action is appropriate when the write fails.

Comment: yes you are right. DMA is not really required, I just tried with a static object and it solved the issue. (But I am creating a new object of struct every time in `msgsnd`s `while` loop, can you tell whether it'll lead to memory leaks)

Comment: So there are at least 3 ways to go.  (1) Don't use DMA and just use a msgst on the stack.  It gets overwritten every time through and no memory leak.  (2) Do what you are (were) doing but remember to delete the object you created with `new` with `delete` every time through the loop.

Comment: (3) DMA the object and just write *the pointer* rather than the whole object to the MQ.  This works because the threads share the same process space and eliminates copying the whole object to the MQ.  That buys you more space to put more objects in the MQ.  The receive side reads the pointer, does its thing and *must* delete the object when done.

Comment: Not type-casting to `(void *)` will detect any bug if you accidentally try to send a non-pointer :)

Answer (score 1):

Probably not related to the issue asked about.

However in `SndMq()` if `recvfrom()` receives  `BUFSIZE` bytes then the code writes out of `buf`'s bounds here:

```
    buf[recvlen] = 0;
```

**Update:**

To fix this changes this line

```
recvlen = recvfrom(fd, buf, BUFSIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&remaddr, &addrlen);
```

to become

```
recvlen = recvfrom(fd, buf, BUFSIZE - 1, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&remaddr, &addrlen);
```

Comment: you are right, but any how its secondary issues... thanks for pointing it out. (currently udp client is sending msg size less than BUFSIZE. I will increase BUFSIZE as and when the udp msg size increases). Please let me know if I am wrong